# Mathematica 10, Show, and PlotRange

Tags: plotting, options

I have recently moved from *Mathematica* 8 to *Mathematica* 10, however I'm having a problem with `PlotRange->All` in combination with Show[].

For example,

```
Show[Table[ListPlot[{{i,i^2}},PlotRange->All],{i,1,10}]]
```

only shows the first point in *Mathematica* 10, but all data points are shown in *Mathematica* 8.

I have tried suggested solutions such as `PlotRangePadding`  but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the `InputForm[]` of the version 10 plot look like?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 14):

When different plots use conflicting options, `Show` uses the first one listed.  So, here it is using the `PlotRange` of the first graphics instance.  Use

```
Show[Table[ListPlot[{{i, i^2}}], {i, 1, 10}], PlotRange -> All]
```

instead to see all the points.

[image]

**Further Explanation**

To see more clearly what is happening, consider the `InputForm` (as suggested by Guesswhoitis) of the first `Plot`.

```
With[{i = 1}, ListPlot[{{i, i^2}}, PlotRange -> All]] // InputForm
```

The output contains `PlotRange -> {{0, 2.}, {0, 2.}}`, which is how `Plot` translates `PlotRange -> All` for the single point given.  For another of the plots, say `i = 10`, it gives as part of the output, `PlotRange -> {{0, 20.}, {0, 200.}}`.  With these conflicting expressions for `PlotRange`, `Show` chooses the first one given, namely the one for `i = 1`.  As it happens, this small range includes only the first `i` value of the ten desired.  The solution above is to give the option `PlotRange` directly to `Show`, overriding any definitions from the individual plots.  This explanation applies to any number of other `Graphics` options.

Comment: I hadn't realised that Show[] could execute the PlotRange command. Thank you for your help. Regards Adam

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to know that:  `Options[Show]` yields an empty list of options; and the doc page for `Show` lists just a single option, namely, `DisplayFunction`. However the Details section of the page for `Show` does state, "Show allows any option that can be applied to graphics to be given."

Comment: @Adam, your take-away from this should be "`Show[]` can be used to override previously set or default settings of `Graphics[]` or `Graphics3D[]`".

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. This is another new-in-10 change to how graphics options work.  OP's code works fine in V9.

Comment: @Michael, I see… now that's quite annoying. I wonder if anyone's complained to WRI about this new behavior.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I usually use `Show[plots, opts]` anyway, in case I have to reorder plots, add something, etc. I hadn't noticed the change until this Q&A.  Perhaps they got lucky and no one else's old code was broken by the change. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is complementary to bbgodfrey's answer:

`PlotRange` is an option for `Graphics`, and `PlotRange -> All` means "show everything".  All the options that can be given in `Graphics` can also be given in plotting functions such as `ListPlot`, `Plot`, etc.  Usually, they have the same meaning as in `Graphics`, but there are exceptions.  `PlotRange` is a fairly subtle exception.

In plotting functions, `PlotRange` controls the range of computed results to be included in the plot, and does not directly translate to the `PlotRange` option of `Graphics`.

For example,

```
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare this with generating the graphics first, then setting `PlotRange` *within* the resulting `Graphics` option

```
Show[%, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that it did something quite different.  In `DensityPlot` it controlled the colour range, which is closely related to what this particular plotting function actually does.  In `Graphics`, it just set the vertical coordinate range.

What does `Show` do?  Since version 6, it has two main functions:

- Set options in existing `Graphics` objects, like I did above.
- Combine several graphics into one.  In this case the options are inherited from the first one.

What happens in your case is that `PlotRange -> All` causes `ListPlot` to figure out a vertical range on its own, and set it explicitly as `PlotRange -> {0., 2.}` in the `Graphics` object it creates.  The rest is explained in the other answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, PlotRange has to be carefully tested precisely because it is only partially passed through to Graphics. :P +1