# Plot has some holes - Show[LogLogPlot[...],LogLogPlot[...]]

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I certainly do not use the Plot feature in Mathematica in its whole glory, but it worked out for me, except for one problem.
I wanted to show some plots in a log-log-manner and it just won't show the
red plot properly, its function beeing $f(t)=(1-\frac{1}{2}t^2)^2$. 
I just wanted to plot it until its minimum, however it cuts when plotting it. 
Extending the plotrange to 5 gives me some part 'suddenly appearing' afterwards  but it wont go down to 0.01 in both cases

[image: Red function doesn't go down]

Comment: Could you please provide your code? That would help greatly.

Comment: No one is going to be able to help you without code.........

Answer (score 3):

As bgodfrey explains in his answer to [(89518)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89518) `Show` will use the `PlotRange` of the first plot given which probably is the case here.

For example plotting your function $f(x) = \left(1 - \alpha\, t^2\right)^2$ for different values of $\alpha$ will show gaps as well:

```
Show[
 {
  Table[ 
    LogLogPlot[ (1 - α t^2)^2, {t, 0.1, 5}, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed]
    ], 
    { α, {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/6} }] (* change the order here to play around *)
  }
 ]
```

[image: Plot with Gaps]

If you play with the order for the list of values in the table for $\alpha$, you will see that the appearance of gaps is depending on the order. For example, try `{1/4, 1/8, 1/6, 1/2}`, e.g. put the $1/2$ to the end of the list of values, and look what happens to your gaps.

Including an explicit `PlotRange` *for each plot* should solve this:

```
Show[
 {
  Table[ 
    LogLogPlot[ (1 - α t^2)^2, {t, 0.1, 5}, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed],
        PlotRange -> { {0.1, 5}, {0.01, 5} }
    ], 
    { α, {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/6} }] (* change the order here to play around *)
  }
 ]
```

[image: Plot without Gaps]

Comment: Or put the `Table` inside the `LogLogPlot`: `LogLogPlot[Evaluate@Table[(1 - \[Alpha] t^2)^2,
   {\[Alpha], {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/6}}], {t, 0.1, 5},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed],
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[StringForm["\[Alpha] = ``", #] & /@ {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 
     1/6}, {.16, .32}]]`

Comment: @Bob Good advice. I wanted to stay true to the bit of code that the OP gave in his title...